# How can I get my cursor into the input box after I set the focus?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, focus, dispatchevent

I am on the site [www.RedBubble.com](http://www.RedBubble.com) with the intent of using javascript to place the active cursor inside the search box at the top. I can get it to focus via code, a popout shows up. But I can't seem to get the cursor to show up inside the box after I get the focus working.

I run the following commands:

```
let searchbar = document.querySelector('input[name="query"]');
const focusEvent = new Event('focus');
const selectEvent = new Event('select');
searchbar.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);
searchbar.dispatchEvent(select);
```

This results in the search input box getting the focus but stubbornly the cursor does not blink inside the input field. If I manually click tab while on the page or I manually click in the box I get both the focus AND the cursor in the box. But I can't seem to re-create this programmatically.

I have also attempted to do this outside of the Developer Console just in case that was what was stealing the focus but I am getting the same result with or without the Developer Console active.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer [here](http://%5Bhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577865/focus-event-with-dispatchevent) explains that dispatching an event does not generate the default action associated with a dispatched event.

You need to call the focus explicity.

```js
let searchbar = document.querySelector('input[name="query"]');
searchbar.focus();
```

```html
<input name="query"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**For a cursor focus try below code, it may help:**

```js
let searchbar = document.querySelector('input[name="query"]');
searchbar.focus();
```